# Where do I go from the Antimatter chamber?

Tags: half-life

I have reached the Antimatter Chamber in Half Life. Where do I go next?
I am roaming around there but do not know actually what to do now.

Comment: Might I suggest a walkthrough if you're unable to progress at all on your own?

Comment: I'd suggest a [walkthrough](http://m.ign.com/wikis/half-life/Walkthrough) for general game instructions

Comment: But I don't get to find any crowbar after the explosion, as mentioned in the walkthrough..

Comment: i HAVE FOUND THE CROWBAR TOO

Comment: I have another aproble. There a place comes where the elevator crashes. How to get out of there ? Climbing down the ladder I find no place to get out. How to ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are verbal prompts from the scientists of what you should be doing in that room.  After they power up the machine, you will need to climb a ladder and push a button to start the rotors.  After more time passes, you will be instructed to move the sample.  Then the game will move on to the next part of the story.